# Listing works but view,add,edit,delete not working in codeigniter crud in mariadb

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, mariadb, grocery-crud

I am trying to run **crud** application with **mariadb** in **codeigniter**.but when i followed every step and run the file..it only showing the listing page..rest is showing 404 Not Found error.
I guess 404 is routing issue but i am unable to find that.
Here is my controller:

```
class Examples extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('grocery_CRUD');
    }

    public function _example_output($output = null)
    {
        $this->load->view('example.php',$output);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //echo "hii"; die;
        $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

        $crud->set_theme('datatables');
        $crud->set_table('admin_user');
        $crud->set_subject('Admin');

        $output = $crud->render();

        $this->_example_output($output);
        //$this->_example_output((object)array('output' => '' , 'js_files' => array() , 'css_files' => array()));
    }

}
```

Am i missing anything here? Please let me know..

Comment: can you remove the .php extension from the view "call" and retry?

Comment: the issue is coming because of nginx server rewrite module issue..but the problem is not solved yet..

Answer (score 1):

you need to put de routes for the functions of GC

```
$route['articles/add']="GroceryCrud_Controller/add";
$route['articles/edit/(:num)']="GroceryCrud_Controller/edit/$1";
$route['articles/read/(:num)']="GroceryCrud_Controller/read/$1";
$route['articles/delete/(:num)']="GroceryCrud_Controller/delete/$1";
```

but if in the form you load an image file, the crud return an error mensage

Answer (score 1):

If you are using *routes* to hide the exact path (controller/method),   for example:

> **file:** routes.php

```
.......

$route['admin/product'] = "admin/products/list";

.......
```

You've the url `www.example.com/admin/product` but the original url path is `www.example.com/admin/products/list` (here, **products** is a controller class and **list** is a method within products class)

You've to specify the original url path to Grocery Crud, under your list method, like this:

```
$crud->set_crud_url_path(site_url('admin/products/list'));
```

That's it, have a good coding. :)